# Detect column id after clicking link

Tags: php, database, list, mysqli, hyperlink

This is a snapcode of my code. I want it to allow user to click the link and show the content. But the list displayed is based on database which I have entered the text and its id. So I want a function that can detect the id when it is clicked and pass the specific value of the id to the tab content. The tab content will decide which id is clicked. if id "1" is clicked, display id "1" content. I'm working on the listing for hotel floor level and display each floor content separately.

```
<li>
   <?php
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
        $result = $conn->query("select * from floors");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            ?><li><a href="#floor" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $row['listfloor'];?></a></li><?php
        }
    ?>                                  
</li>

<div class="tab-content>
  <div id="floor" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <?php
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
        $result = $conn->query("select * from floors");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if ("the value of id clicked by user")
        {
            echo include 'groundfloor.php';
        }
     ?>                         
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `$_GET` and add an `WHERE` statement in your SQL query. Nothing complicated.

Comment: can you give an example syntax? I'm quite new to php programming

Comment: Then you should google and learn how to use `$_GET` in PHP. Its part of the fundamentals of PHP, you should really do some researchs and learn about it. No need for an example here, there are tons of exampels on the web. Do your research, if you still don't understand how it works, then come back and I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

On the page with the links, change:

```
href="#floor"
```

to

```
href="#floor?id=<?= $row['listfloorid]; ?>"
```

And on your list page change the query to:

```
<?php $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
$result = $conn->query("select * from floors");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

?>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="<?= $row['listfloorid']; ?>" class="tab - pane fade in">
        <?php
            echo include $row['floorname'] . '.php';
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I can just echo the id row in href and put the id value in tab content. But this is from the database. What if admin want to add another new floor? I can't just duplicate the function in tab content. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is working

in the link

```
<li><a href="#floor<?php echo $row['id'];?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $row['listfloor'];?></a></li>
```

in the tab content

```
<div class="tab content">
  <div id="floor1" class="tab-pane fade in">    
        <?php echo include 'groundfloor.php'; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is I want to have only 1 function for the whole floor. So I don't have to duplicate the syntax over again if there is a new floor added by administrator